“Coals of fire” in ‘The Dying Detective’ by Arthur Conan Doyle
In the story ‘The Adventure of the Dying Detective’ (1913) by Arthur Conan Doyle, Sherlock Holmes, who seems to be dying of “a coolie disease from Sumatra”, is visited by Culverton Smith, “a well-known resident of Sumatra” with “unique experience of this disease, the investigation of which has been his dearest hobby”.

“Is that you, Mr. Smith?” Holmes whispered. “I hardly dared hope that you would come.”
The other laughed.
“I should imagine not,” he said. “And yet, you see, I am here. Coals of fire, Holmes—coals of fire!”

What does Culverton Smith mean by “coals of fire”?

“Coals of fire” alludes to Paul’s Epistle to the Romans:

Dearly beloved, avenge not yourselves, but rather give place unto wrath: for it is written, Vengeance is mine; I will repay, saith the Lord. Therefore if thine enemy hunger, feed him; if he thirst, give him drink: for in so doing thou shalt heap coals of fire on his head.
Romans 12:19–20. Authorized Version.

Here the coals of fire are the pains of remorse felt by someone who has been treated kindly by their enemy. Possibly Paul was alluding in this passage to Song of Songs 8:6, which says that “the coals [of jealousy] are coals of fire, which hath a most vehement flame”.
In the story, Culverton Smith and Sherlock Holmes are enemies, for Holmes suspects Smith of having murdered Victor Savage. So Smith means that by treating Holmes with kindness (visiting him in his illness), he is heaping these pains of remorse on his enemy’s head.
